# Python function returns non-type in AWS Glue even the same function working in local machine

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, aws-glue

i am new to AWS glue. I have a created job that would modify phone number's from a column and update the data frame.
Below script working fine in my local machine where i running with pyspark,
This basically add '+00' against those phone numbers which are not starting with '0'

```
## Phonenubercolum
6-451-512-3627
0-512-582-3548
1-043-733-0050

def addCountry_code(phoneNo):
    countryCode= '+00'+phoneNo
    if phoneNo[:1] !='0':
        return str(countryCode)
    else:
        return str(phoneNo)

phone_replace_udf=udf(lambda x: addCountry_code(x), StringType())

phoneNo_rep_DF= concatDF.withColumn("phoneNumber", phone_replace_udf(sf.col('phoneNumber')))#.drop('phoneNumber')
##output
+006-451-512-3627
0-512-582-3548
+001-043-733-0050
```

But when i ran the same code in the glue context, it throws following error

```
addCountry_code countryCode= '+00'+phoneNo **TypeError: must be str, not NoneType**
```

I am wondering how this function fails in glue?

Appreciate if anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give the desired result. Use [spark.udf.register](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration.register) to register the function

```
import json
import boto3
import pyspark.sql.dataframe
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

ds = [{'phoneNumber': '6-451-512-3627'},
{'phoneNumber': '0-512-582-3548'},
{'phoneNumber': '1-043-733-0050'}]

sf = spark.createDataFrame(ds)

def addCountry_code(phoneNo):
    countryCode= '+00'+phoneNo
    if phoneNo[:1] !='0':
        return str(countryCode)
    else:
        return str(phoneNo)



spark.udf.register('phone_replace_udf', lambda x: addCountry_code(x), StringType())
sf.createOrReplaceTempView('sf')
spark.sql('select phone_replace_udf(phoneNumber) from sf').collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without using udf (udfs are generally slower than in-built functions).

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, lit

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

## Phonenubercolum
ds = [{'PhoneNumber': '6-451-512-3627'},
{'PhoneNumber': '0-512-582-3548'},
{'PhoneNumber': '1-043-733-0050'}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(ds)

df = df.withColumn('PhoneNumber', when(
    ~df['PhoneNumber'].startswith('0'), concat(lit('+00'), df['PhoneNumber'])) \
    .otherwise(df['PhoneNumber']))


df.show()

+-----------------+
|      PhoneNumber|
+-----------------+
|+006-451-512-3627|
|   0-512-582-3548|
|+001-043-733-0050|
+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank You @theredcomet. However iam not able to import 'lit' here even i imported sql function as follows 
'from pyspark.sql import functions as sf." 
 How do can import lit ?

Comment: I found '_lit_doc' is the substitute of 'lit', so i modified with '_lit_doc'' in the above code. But now iam getting Type error as follows
"   sf.concat(_lit_doc(numberTadd), concatDF['phoneNumber'])).otherwise
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Hi @theredcomet, i got to know the lit issue which is fixed. But real scenario is, i need to add '+00' against those value which is 'not starts with 0'. ?